# How to understand this ACF

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have two time series. After calculating the ACF, they are like the plot below.

Does anyone know the meaning of this ACF plot?

I know it's non-stationary time series, but I don't know how the lags can help me to build the model.

My data are as below:

Year,Parea,Uarea

1950,3435829.43 ,144179.7476

1955,3619503.16 ,168028.4699

1960,3881482.63 ,196839.0495

1965,4310040.34 ,229032.161

1970,4950230.51 ,262543.7928

1975,6216028.19 ,297502.4439

1980,7062749.74 ,337481.6276

1985,8187770.34 ,381059.4338

1990,9893501.67 ,432255.4666

1995,12011196.93 ,487330.1703

2000,13327189.88 ,546829.7056

2005,15231484.09 ,612606.1358

2010,16986859.05 ,683200.605

2014,18097951.40 ,743693

And I have doubts about my sample size and time-series data analysis~
My purpose for these data analysis are:

1) do the Granger Causal Relation Test between PArea and UArea.

2) build ARIMAs for PArea and UArea, respectively.

But my data points are only 14, may be insufficient for purpose of my data analysis~
I wander if I can interpolate the values between the middle years to extend sample range?

[image: ACF of a time-series data with 14 points]

Comment: what does the data look like? What does the PACF (or the IACF) look like?

Comment: With confidence bands that wide, your sample size is very likely too small for any serious model building. Either way, show us the data too.

Comment: Yes, I was confused about the sample size and time-series modelling~ My data is between 1950-2014 with 5 years interval (except the last is between 2010~2014).I will put my data above, and I consider whether can I interpolate values between the middle 5 years to solve the problem~

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting the data. To a good first approximation, your data show exponential trends, as shown by a nearly linear plot with logarithmic scale for the response axis. Here you are. I would have shown units of measurement for the areas had I known what they should be.

[image]

For this kind of data, and for this sample size, **calculating autocorrelation of the raw data is essentially useless**, as at best the results reflect the trend in the data that is evident any way.

Some people would want to fit a model and look at the autocorrelation of the residuals here. That would make more sense statistically.

Clearly your data are not quite equally spaced. Make sure that you are explicit about that with your software. Interpolating to get data every year would not be completely crazy, but would not be a good idea unless you took account of that in your modelling. I can't see how to do that, as most of your points would be interpolated, and the gain in degrees of freedom would be essentially spurious.

If your purpose is to understand these data, I doubt that you have enough data to make the proposed models and tests a very good idea. If your purpose is to learn about ARIMA models and Granger causality, you need a better dataset for the purpose.

Note: I doubt that any area is known to 10 significant figures!

Comment: Thanks for advising~ You mean that, this dataset is too small for time-series modelling~Actually, I want to study the relationship between the development of these two variables~After reading some material about time-series data analysis, I came out the idea that maybe I can use Granger causality and ARIMA models to achieve the purpose~

Comment: If I have a panel dataset, not just these two sequence for a region, but I have these two sequence for many countries, can I use them to study the relationship between these two variables?

Comment: And I didn't really understand your last sentence in the note, what does that mean?

Comment: Some people would fit time series models here. To me, it's more of a regression problem and there may (should!) be substantive knowledge that can be brought to bear to discuss minor deviations from the trends. There is no magic threshold sample size that (in)validates the techniques you are interested in, but I'd say that you would be stretching their applicability mightily. You may get different opinions here from others; that's why it's called a forum.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: A question about what to do with panel data should be a new question.